# ExecutorService - create new instances in method vs one per class

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, executorservice

Should I create new ExecutorService in every method call or use one per class? Which is preferred option in terms of performance?

```
public class NotificationService {

    public void sendNotification(User recipient) {

        ExecutorService notificationsPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        // code

        notificationsPool.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Or

```
public class NotificationService {

    ExecutorService notificationsPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    public void sendNotification(User recipient) {

        // code
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't choose this based on performance. You choose this based on what is needed. Do you need 10 new threads to send a notification to a user? What's the point of having a pool of 10 reusable threads if you only use one of them, only once (assuming that's what sending a notification to a user would do)?

Comment: User may be related with more than 1 key. However, it's not good code example which was modified before posting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your first code snippet the `ExecutorService` is local, i.e. a new `ExecutorService` is created on each method call and the `ExecutorService` is terminated at the end of the method. As a consequence the threads aren't reused when the method runs the next time. In the second snippet the `ExecutorService` and its threads are kept as long as the `NotificationService` instance is alive. As you can see there are not only less instances of `ExecutorService` to be GC'd but there are less threads to create and they can be reused. As an additional bonus the second method does not incur any no warmup time for thread creation after the `ExecutorService` has been created.

If you have multiple instances of `NotificationService` you should declare `notificationsPool` as `static` in order to share the pool and its threads between all the instances.

If the amount of threads needed varies depending on the amount of notifications that have to be sent, use a cached thread pool (`ExecutorService#newCachedThreadPool()`), maybe with an upper limit.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on two questions:

- what grade of parallelization do you need?
- what amount of overhead is acceptable to you?

Do you really need 10 threads to solve the problem in the function? And do you need to be able, to process the function twice (thus giving 20 threads to it)? Do you even have the ressources, to do so?

Or what would happen if you allocate a threadPool to the class? Would you probably run into problems by doing so (blocking due to the thread pool being used up)?

Given enough ressources, option 1 could be faster IF the task to be solved is large enough to justify the overhead from creating that executor every time the function is called. Though honestly I hardly can imagine a notification THAT intense.

Thus, without more information I'd point to option 2 (assuming it to be static of course). Also you might take a look into the new WorkStealingPool, it might help you use the precise level of parallelism.